# Loss of references between service and controller data in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

We encountered a problem when working with references between service and controller data

```
// We have a service that we use to store id and some other data
app.service('testService', function ($http, serverURL) {
    var self = this;
    self.data = {
        id: null,
        token: null,
        ....
    };
    self.initMe = function () {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: serverURL + '/initMe/' + '?token=' + self.data.token
        });
    };
    return self;
});
meModule.controller('MeCtrl', function (testService, ...) {
    $scope.me = testService.data; // we make a connection between the scope and the controller

    $rootScope.$on('initMe', function (e, data) {
        testService.initMe().success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // typeof(data.result) === 'object'
            // $scope.me = data.result;         // Doesn't work
            // OR
            // testService.data = data.result;    // Doesn't work

            testService.data = data.result; //  
            $scope.me = testService.data;   // It works, but we have to recover
                                            // the references between scope and service
        });
    });
}
```

Questions

1. Why we loose the connection between scope and service in $scope.me =
   data.result or meService.data = data.result;?
2. Maybe there are other, nicer ways to update the data in a sevice
   from an external API (Get requests)?

Comment: Try changing `var self = this;` to `var self = {};`

Answer (score 3):

That's just how JavaScript works. Consider the following example:

```
> first = { data: null }
{ data: null }
> second = { data: first.data }
{ data: null }
> first.data = "something"
'something'
> second.data
null
```

There is an incorrect assertion on this line:

```
$scope.me = testService.data; // we make a connection ...
```

There is no actual connection between the scope and the service; you're just copying the simple value over. However, if you store off a *reference to an object*, you can update that object *in place* and the "connection" will be kept. Consider this example:

```
> first = { data: {} }
{ data: {} }
> second = { data: first.data }
{ data: {} }
> first.data['something'] = 'stuff'
'stuff'
> second.data
{ something: 'stuff' }
```

Comment: So which path should I choose? According to your answer I see two possiblities:
1. Change the structure of the testService.data object and bind to object  'o':
`self.data = {
 o: {
  id: null,
        token: null,
        ....
 }
}`
2. When assigning service data to scope  use for..in for the object and assign every property separatly.

Am I right or there is a better solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Service is like a constructor function. You do not do return on the constructor function.

I am not sure about what you mean by loosing connection. But the object `data` that you create on the service should not get reassigned anytime within the service. You are currently updating the data in the controller. The same can be done in service.

Also the asignment that you have highlighted `$scope.me = data.result;` will cause a controller to point to a different instance of data than what the service has.

The overall problem is with reference that the service and controller point to.